# How convert and save date as mysql format?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Have a form and its consist of 10 date fields, and user can pick upto 10 dates. Picking in the format 'D, d M, Y'. How can i convert this format to mysql date format and save into database....

```
<input type='text' name='day1' id='datepicker1' value='' maxlength="50" style="color:#999999" readonly="readonly"/>
<input type='text' name='day2' id='datepicker2' value='' maxlength="50" style="color:#999999" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use [`strtotime`](http://ca.php.net/strtotime), you can convert the date into a timestamp, and reformat it for MySQL using [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

**Example:**

```
$day1 = strtotime($_REQUEST['day1']);
$day1sql = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $day1);
```

You then want to use `$day1sql` to insert into MySQL. Repeat for your other dates. For more information, [have a look at this](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql).

Comment: Thanks...Francois..Where I want to put this script. Inside the form?

Comment: @Saam - No! This goes in your PHP script where you handle the form submission and insert in your database.

Comment: Ok... but what the thing is i am using http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html. Can you check this one? Pls check fg_membersite...

Comment: @Saam - I would add it at the top of the `InsertIntoDB` function. You'll want to use `$formvars['day1']` instead of `$_REQUEST['day1']` it seems like.

Answer (score 0):

Tell MySQL about [your format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in the [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple in Java - you can convert a value obtained from an HTML Date widget like this:

```
//Assume HTML widget returns 2015-05-25 
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date fromDate1 = format.parse(fromDate);
```